# Equivalence of definitions of the axiom of induction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

Definition 1:

$(0\in S, n\in S \implies n+1\in S) \implies n\in S \forall n≥0$.

Definition 2:

$(P(0), P(n)\implies P(n+1)) \implies P(n) \forall n≥0$.

To prove the equivalence of these definitions, the only thing needed is the "relabelling" $n \mapsto P(n), S\mapsto T$, where $T$ is the set of truths?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$S \mapsto T$, where $T$ is the set of truths".

Comment: Hmm I may have been unclear, I meant, for example that $0\in S$ is equivalent to $P(0)\in True$.

Comment: Put the relation $S=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid P(n)\}$

Answer (score 1):

To prove definition 2 from definition 1 let $S = \{n \ | \ P(n)\}$ and to prove definition 1 from definition 2 let $P(n)$ be the statement "$n \in S$".